# awk to create html table adds space at the end of each data entry

Tags: html, awk

I am using below code for creating html table from an input file which works perfectly fine, However while creating the html table it adds a space to each entry to a cell. How do I avoid getting space at the end?

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "<tr>";print "<th>NAME</th>";print "<th>POLICY</th>";print "<th>STATUS</th>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}' /tmp/output/Report_$(date -d '-1 day' '+%d-%b-%Y') >> /tmp/output/Report_$(date -d '-1 day' '+%d-%b-%Y').html]
```

now in the input file entries are going through script as `echo "$x $y $z" >> /tmp/output/Report_$(date -d '-1 day' '+%d-%b-%Y')`

Let me know how can i avoid spaces at the end of each data entry to a cell.

Input File

```
cat /tmp/t
    Cindy   Today   Standard
    Victor  Today   Standard
    Bob     Today   Standard
    Martha  Tomorrow    Oracle
    Sam     Tomorrow    Oracle
```

Guys the problem with my code was it had `<tr></tr>` and `<td></td>` with a new line each time which added an extra unnecessary space to the final sheet cell>

Before the output was:
Thanks @karakfa, It did the trick, the issue in my code was every  was with new line, meaning it will append a space in the actual data.

Simply the difference in final output from before and after is
Before:

```
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
</tr>
```

After:

```
<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td></tr>
<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td></tr>
```

Comment: show your sample input and expected output.

Comment: what is the point of creating the file line by line with `echo`s?  I don't think the space is your biggest problem.  Also why are you recreating the file name for each line of echo?

Comment: So... what's the expected output of the awk command you are asking for help with?

Comment: So let me get this straight... The real problem here occurs when you *try to copy paste the table data to an excel sheet*? Sid, I hate to be a snarky-pants, but .. you've got myriad code problems, invalid HTML output, email that doesn't follow RFC 822 or its derivatives, and now you reveal in a comment that the actual problem has Microsoft Excel on one side. I guess this is an [XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) after all. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not efficient but a cleaner way of generating a html table with helper functions

```
awk 'function wrap(tag,x) {return "<"tag">"x"</"tag">"}
     function table(x)    {return wrap("table",ORS x)}
     function row(x)      {return wrap("tr",x) ORS}
     function cell(x)     {return wrap("td",x)}

     BEGIN {print table(row(cell(1) cell(2) cell(3)))}'

<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

with non-static data, perhaps this is better

```
$ awk 'function wrap(tag,x) {return "<"tag">"x"</"tag">"}
       function row(x)      {return wrap("tr",x)}
       function cell(x)     {return wrap("td",x)}

      BEGIN {print "<table>"}
            {print row(cell($1) cell($2) cell($3))}
      END   {print "</table>"}' <(echo -e "1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9")

<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: karakfa, I like this function set. Cool way to handle this kind of output. Ima gonna steal it. :-)

Comment: Thanks @karakfa, It did the trick, the issue in my code was every <td></td> was with new line, meaning it will append a space in the actual data.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't include enough information to replicate the problem you're having, so the best we can do at this point is guess, and suggest better ways to do the stuff that you *have* included.

What about building your output using printf formatting? Using formatting will allow you to control your output much more precisely.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    printf "<table>\n"
    printf "<tr>\n <th>NAME</th> <th>POLICY</th> <th>STATUS</th>\n</tr>"
    fmtrow="<tr>\n%s</tr>"
    fmttd="\t<td>%s</td>\n"
  }
  {
    data=""
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) data=data sprintf(fmttd, $i)
    printf fmtrow, data
  }
  END {
    printf "\n</table>\n"
  }
'
```

This implements the same functionality you had in your original script, with the for loop stepping through columns to build each row. If you know you'll only have three columns, you can simplify things:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    printf "<table>\n"
    printf "<tr>\n\t<th>NAME</th>\n\t<th>POLICY</th>\n\t<th>STATUS</th>\n</tr>"
    fmtrow="<tr>\n\t<td>%s</td>\n\t<td>%s</td>\n\t<td>%s</td>\n</tr>"
  }
  {
    printf fmtrow, $1, $2, $3
  }
  END {
    printf "\n</table>\n"
  }
'
```

Bear in mind that this just recycles your input, it doesn't clean it. If the source data file has been edited on a Microsoft Windows machine, it might have Ctrl-M characters added to the end of each line, which awk would simply treat as part of the last field.